# Handwritten mapper for List<T>

Tags: c#, mapping

How best way to handwritten mapping `List<T1>` to `List<T2>`?

My example class:

```
public class T1
{
    public int ID {get; set}
    public string Name {get; set}
}

public class T2
{
    public int ID {get; set}
    public string Name {get; set}
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do? what is your goal?

Comment: Don't do this manually, use external tool like automapper, this is the best way.

Comment: Is implementing your own mapper a fundamental requirement to you, if not check https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper, otherwise have a look at .Net Reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
public static class Mapper
{
    public static T1 ToT1(T2 t)
    {
        return new T1 { ID = t.ID, Name = t.Name };
    }

    public static T2 ToT2(T1 t)
    {
        return new T2 { ID = t.ID, Name = t.Name };
    }
}

List<T1> listOfT1 = listOfT2.Select(Mapper.ToT1).ToList();
List<T2> listOfT2 = listOfT1.Select(Mapper.ToT2).ToList();
```

Or if you have access to change the code, I recommend adding an interface:

```
public IMyInterface
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public static class Mapper
{
    public static TResult Map<TInput, TResult>(TInput t) 
        where TInput : IMyInterface
        where TResult : IMyInterface, new
    {
        return new TResult { ID = t.ID, Name = t.Name };
    }
}

List<T1> listOfT1 = listOfT2.Select(Mapper.Map<T1, T2>).ToList();
List<T2> listOfT2 = listOfT1.Select(Mapper.Map<T2, T1>).ToList();
```

You can improve this a little bit by taking advantage of inferred type parameters, so you only have to specify the result type:

```
public static class Mapper<TResult>
    where TResult : IMyInterface, new
{
    public static TResult Map<TInput, TResult>(TInput t) 
        where TInput : IMyInterface
    {
        return new TResult { ID = t.ID, Name = t.Name };
    }
}

List<T1> listOfT1 = listOfT2.Select(Mapper<T1>.Map).ToList();
List<T2> listOfT2 = listOfT1.Select(Mapper<T2>.Map).ToList();
```

One added benefit of this second method is that sometimes you may not need to do any mapping, just using a `List<IMyInterface>` may be sufficient for either type.

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to do this manually, then handy way is extension methods:

```
public static T2 ToT2(this T1 t1)
{
    return new T2 { ID = t1.ID, Name = t1.Name };
}

public static List<T2> ToT2List(this IEnumerable<T1> t1List)
{
    return t1List.Select(t1 => t1.ToT2()).ToList();
}
```

Usage:

```
T2 t2 = t1.ToT2();
List<T2> t2List = t1List.ToT2List();
```

But I suggest you to use [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) (or other mapping tool), which will use reflection to match properties by name.

Comment: This is exactly how I do it if I don't use automapper. but do aim for automapper :)